# Number of occurances of Highest & 2nd Highest values after groupby in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below

```html
Itr Type Start Values
2 1 101 20.402
2 1 102 20.402
2 1 103 20.399
2 1 104 20.399
2 1 105 20.399
2 1 106 20.383
2 1 107 20.383
2 1 108 20.383
2 1 109 20.383
2 1 110 20.383
2 1 111 20.36
2 1 112 20.36
2 1 113 20.36
2 1 114 20.36
2 1 115 20.36
2 1 116 20.36
2 1 117 20.36
2 1 118 20.36
2 1 119 20.36
2 1 120 20.36
3 1 121 20.348
3 1 122 20.348
3 1 123 20.348
3 1 124 20.348
3 1 125 20.348
3 1 126 20.34
3 1 127 20.34
3 1 128 20.34
3 1 129 20.34
3 1 130 20.34
3 1 131 20.337
3 1 132 20.337
3 1 133 20.337
3 1 134 20.337
3 1 135 20.337
3 1 136 20.342
3 2 121 20.058
3 2 122 20.058
3 2 123 20.058
3 2 124 20.058
3 2 125 20.043
3 2 126 20.043
3 2 127 20.043
3 2 128 20.043
3 2 129 20.043
3 2 130 20.035
3 2 131 20.035
3 2 132 20.035
3 2 133 20.035
3 2 134 20.035
3 2 135 20.021
```

I want to do a  groupby of iterations (Itr) & Type & then find the number of occurrences of the maximum value & number of occurrences of the 2nd maximum value.
For example for a groupby of Irr 2 & cycle 1, the result should be 2 & 3 because 20.402 (the maximum value) occurs twice & 20.399 (2nd max value) occurs thrice. I have tried but not been successful .Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Comment: If i do `df.groupby(['Itr','Type'])['Values'].value_counts()` , I get the counts of each of the values but I am unable to get the value corresponding to max or min. even average of each Itr & Type group. If i give mean() it will give mean for everything. Not just the individual grouped data

Comment: [np.unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) also lends itself to this task since it automatically takes the unique values, sorts, and returns the counts with `return_counts=True`. Here's how you can use it in this case: `df.groupby(['Itr', 'Type'])['Values'].apply(lambda x: list(zip(*np.unique(x, return_counts=True)))[-2:])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get a mask of the top values within each group. Then get the size of the masked DataFrame.

```
m = df.groupby(['Itr', 'Type'])['Values'].transform(lambda x: x.isin(x.drop_duplicates().nlargest(2)))
df.where(m).groupby(['Itr', 'Type', 'Values']).size()

Itr  Type  Values
2.0  1.0   20.399    3
           20.402    2
3.0  1.0   20.342    1
           20.348    5
     2.0   20.043    5
           20.058    4
dtype: int64
```

---

Alternatively with `groupby` + `value_counts`, then `sort` and `groupby` + `tail` to keep the 2 largest values within groups.

```
(df.groupby(['Itr', 'Type'])['Values'].value_counts()
   .sort_index(level=2)
   .groupby(level=[0, 1]).tail(2))

Itr  Type  Values
3    2     20.043    5
           20.058    4
     1     20.342    1
           20.348    5
2    1     20.399    3
           20.402    2
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If i have to get the number of occurrences of ONLY the 2nd largest value (not 1st &  2nd). How do i get that? Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out. Instead of `tail(2)` i used `take([-2])` to get the 2nd value from the bottom.